# cant install or remove anything on 18.04 cause of DPKG error

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, dpkg

Last time I was able to install is install adobe using snap now I cant install anything and having multiple errors; when I run sudo dpkg --configure -a , sudo apt-get -f install I get below

```
martin@martin:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up php-pear (1:1.10.8+submodules+notgz-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: dpkg: error: unknown option --validate-version

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
dpkg: error processing package php-pear (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up mysql-common (5.8+1.0.4) ...
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: dpkg: error: unknown option --validate-version

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
dpkg: error processing package mysql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up mysql-utilities (1.6.4-1) ...
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: dpkg: error: unknown option --validate-version

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
dpkg: error processing package mysql-utilities (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up apache2 (2.4.29-1ubuntu4.13) ...
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: dpkg: error: unknown option --validate-version

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up git (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.7) ...
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: dpkg: error: unknown option --validate-version

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
dpkg: error processing package git (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php-pear
 mysql-common
 mysql-utilities
 apache2
 git
martin@martin:~$
```

This is a copy of my /var/lib/dpkg/status

```
  GNU nano 2.9.3                                                  /var/lib/dpkg/status                                                            

Description: API library for scanners -- utilities
 SANE stands for "Scanner Access Now Easy" and is an application
 programming interface (API) that provides standardized access to any
 raster image scanner hardware (flatbed scanner, hand-held scanner,
 video- and still-cameras, frame-grabbers, etc.). The SANE standard is
 free and its discussion and development are open to everybody. The
 current source code is written to support several operating systems,
 including GNU/Linux, OS/2, Win32 and various Unices and is available
 under the GNU General Public License (commercial applications and
 backends are welcome, too, however).
 .
 This package includes the command line frontend scanimage, the saned
 server and the sane-find-scanner utility, along with their documentation.
Homepage: http://www.sane-project.org
Original-Maintainer: Jörg Frings-Fürst <debian@jff-webhosting.net>

Package: python-yaml
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: python
Installed-Size: 468
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: pyyaml
Version: 3.12-1build2
Depends: python (<< 2.8), python (>= 2.7~), python:any (<< 2.8), python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~), libc6 (>= 2.14), libyaml-0-2
Description: YAML parser and emitter for Python
 Python-yaml is a complete YAML 1.1 parser and emitter for Python.  It can parse
 all examples from the specification. The parsing algorithm is simple enough to
 be a reference for YAML parser implementors. A simple extension API is also
 provided.  The package is built using libyaml for improved speed.

^G Get Help     ^O Write Out    ^W Where Is     ^K Cut Text     ^J Justify      ^C Cur Pos      M-U Undo        M-A Mark Text   M-] To Bracket
^X Exit         ^R Read File    ^\ Replace      ^U Uncut Text   ^T To Spell     ^_ Go To Line   M-E Redo        M-6 Copy Text   M-W WhereIs Next
```

When I try removing php-pear

```
martin@martin:~$ sudo apt-get remove php-pear
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  php-cli php-xml php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-json php7.2-opcache php7.2-readline php7.2-xml
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  php-pear
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 2,117 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 173197 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing php-pear (1:1.10.8+submodules+notgz-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: dpkg: error: unknown option --validate-version

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
dpkg: error processing package php-pear (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: dpkg: error: unknown option --validate-version

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php-pear
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
martin@martin:~$
```

EDIT:

```
martin@martin:~$ python -V
Python 2.7.17
martin@martin:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
martin@martin:~$
```

dpkg:

```
martin@martin:~$ dpkg --version
Debian `dpkg' package management program version 1.17.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
martin@martin:~$
```

Comment: Please add the output of `python -V` and `which python`

Comment: Question with same error message: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181590/apt-get-install-package-gets-error, but not resolved

Comment: And `dpkg --version` :-)

Comment: @pLumo updated.

Comment: so this is the root issue. [18.04 has dpkg version 1.19.0.5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/dpkg). I have no clue how you got a wrong dpkg version installed and how you reverse it ... Maybe try downloading the `deb` and install manually. Problem is of course that for installing a `deb`, you use `dpkg`.... if that is not working you have a problem. Maybe you need to compile and install from source? or maybe someone else can help or [see this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878887/how-to-reinstall-dpkg).

Comment: i see. atleast now I know the root cause maybe I find a fix or try your solution could you  answer that?

Comment: try my answer. As for me everything is working fine i cannot test it though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dpkg` has wrong version somehow, Ubuntu 18.04 currently [has version 1.19.0.5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/dpkg). You need to reinstall `dpkg`:

Try this:

```
sudo -i
mkdir /tmp/dpkg
cd /tmp/dpkg
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/366329727/dpkg_1.19.0.5ubuntu2_amd64.deb
ar x dpkg*.deb data.tar.xz
tar xvf data.tar.xz ./usr/bin/dpkg
cp ./usr/bin/dpkg /usr/bin/
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
```

From [can't install software--can I fix missing dpkg?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474646/cant-install-software-can-i-fix-missing-dpkg/474681#474681)

Comment: im getting no entry data.tar.gz in archive from ar x dpkg*.deb data.tar.gz

Comment: Yeah just noticed it is `.xz` and not `.gz` in the deb file. See my update

Comment: that is "good", as it indeed fixes the dpkg issue, but you have other issues, too. Try: `a2dismod mpm_prefork`, then try again.

Comment: that did the trick. Now i just need to fix problem with apache not starting I think I can handle that now thank you very much. I wish i have you brains and ubuntu knowledge :)

Comment: Great :-) If you have problems with that, you can ask another question.

Comment: I will try to solve for now.and ask if i cant take it anymore. It took me a whole week to solve this one with your help.

Comment: hi I did try to solve but I cant can you help me [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248804/apache-2-installed-but-not-starting-in-ubuntu-18-04)