# Upgrading to 20.04 from 18.04

Tags: 18.04, package-management, dpkg, 20.04

I am having alot of error in my dpkg and I am at my limit of fixing it. I cant install or update or remove packages. I've tried many solution but all fails and ends up at

> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

If i upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 will this fix my dpkg problem?

EDIT:

sample output:

```
martin@martin:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libapt-inst1.5 libapt-pkg4.12
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.9) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: dpkg: error: unknown option --validate-version

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
martin@martin:~$
```

Comment: no, upgrading to 20.04 will not work if you don't fix that issue, but without the full output or at least the original error message we are not able to help. In 99% of cases there is an answer here on that site.

Comment: An upgrade might fail if you do not first fix the problem. A fresh install will sure solve it. The error code (1) is very general and just means that it returned an error. It is not very likely that anybody will be able to help you with only this information. you will have to elaborate.

Comment: @pLumo actually I asked a question let me link it here [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248699/cant-install-or-remove-anything-on-18-04-cause-of-dpkg-error)

Comment: okay, then we should stick to one question please. I vote to close this one in favor of the other one.

Comment: I would disagree but if you think it necessary then no problem @pLumo