# Apache 2 installed but not starting in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, apache2

I have installed apache on ubuntu 18.04 but when I try to start it I am getting : `apache2: error while loading shared libraries: libapr-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

```
martin@martin:~$ sudo ufw app list
Available applications:
  Apache
  Apache Full
  Apache Secure
  CUPS
  OpenSSH
martin@martin:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

martin@martin:~$ apache2 -version
apache2: error while loading shared libraries: libapr-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
martin@martin:~$
```

What seem to be causing the problem

EDIT

```
martin@martin:~$ sudo apt-get install libapr1 libapr1-dev 
[sudo] password for martin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libapr1 is already the newest version (1.6.3-2).
libapr1-dev is already the newest version (1.6.3-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
martin@martin:~$ sudo apt-get install libapr-1.so.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libapr-1.so.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libapr-1.so.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libapr-1.so.0'
martin@martin:~$
```

UPDATE:

```
martin@martin:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapr-1*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 394910 Feb 25  2018 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapr-1.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    958 Feb 25  2018 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapr-1.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     17 Feb 25  2018 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapr-1.so -> libapr-1.so.0.6.3
```

---

```
martin@martin:~$ ldd /usr/sbin/apache2
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff8e0f3000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f8948139000)
    libaprutil-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaprutil-1.so.0 (0x00007f8947f0e000)
    libapr-1.so.0 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8947cef000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f89478fe000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f89476c6000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f8947494000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8948651000)
    libapr-1.so.0 => not found
```

Comment: Hi, please tray `sudo apt update; sudo apt install --fix-broken; sudo apt install --reinstall apache2`. It looks like the mentioned library is broken or not installed in some way.

Comment: i did try reintalling but not working too

Comment: run sudo apt-get update --fix-missing and then update all software. then restart and run Apache again

Comment: `libapr-1.so` needs to be a symbolic link in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` to `libapr-1.so.xxxxx` where `xxxxx` is a version number. `libapr-1.so.xxxxx` must be a real file in the same directory. Check whether this is so. If you have no link called `libapr-1.so` but do have the `xxxxx` file, create the symbolic link and restart Apache.

Comment: @Jos i dont understand what you mean though

Comment: Do `ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapr-1*`.  [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1248804/edit) your question and add the output of the command to it.

Comment: @Jos updating the OP

Comment: You have the link, but not the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was probably resolved, but you were probably missing the package libaprutil1: Apache Portable Runtime library. For Debian based operating systems such as Ubuntu, run:

first try configure dynamic linker run-time bindings

`ldconfig`

If this don't solve your problem try to reinstall libaprutil1

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall libaprutil1`

Comment: actually its not yet resolved. I think i tried installing that one but I will try it again to find out

Comment: tried both didnt solve my issue

Comment: what should i get when i run ldconfig i didnt get any response

Comment: Did you restart apache2 service after reinstalling the libaprutil1